# Copying taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am working on a website of restaurant company. On the front page i am able to visit one of its restaurants. Each of this restaurant subpages has its own taxonomy (Menu, About us, Contact) and content assigned to them.

Is there any elegant solution for copying this taxonomy, and therefore creating new restaurant? (lets suppose, we have two restaurants in Berlin and Paris, and we want to add new restaurant in London)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it can be considered an "elegant" solution, but the [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module might be of help.

You would need to export your taxonomy, edit the CSV, and then import the new data back into your site.

Hope that helps,

Comment: it works, but it is not user-friendly for non-developers.